# Component Exception when seperating function into different files and importing

Tags: react-native

In App.js

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import React from 'react';
import { Page1 } from './Page1';
import { Page2 } from './Page2';



const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Page1" component={Page1} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Page2" component={Page2} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I need help in solving this error. when I add these functions in App.js the app works fine but i want to split each screen into different .js file to clean up my code.

```
Error: Couldn't find a 'component', 'getComponent' or 'children' prop for the screen 'Page1'. This can happen if you passed 'undefined'. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or mixed up default import and named import when importing.

This error is located at:
    in StackNavigator (at App.js:18)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:409)
    in ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer) (at NavigationContainer.tsx:91)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:90)
    in ForwardRef(NavigationContainer) (at App.js:17)
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in RootErrorBoundary (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make these changes in App.js

```js
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import React from 'react';
import Page1 from './Page1';
import Page2 from './Page2';



const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Page1" component={Page1} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Page2" component={Page2} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```